# How do I differentiate radio buttons in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement

> This is my code and when I try to run it and when I select 
>   headache, sweating, weakness, chills, bone pain and joint pain viralfever.class activity gets started instead of chickengunia.class. What is the problem here?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.questionnaire);


    final Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && chills.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, ViralFever.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }

  else   if (headache.isChecked() && bonepain.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && rashes.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Dengue.class);`enter code here`
                startActivity(Intents);

            }

else    if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && skinyellow.isChecked() && palestools.isChecked() && abdoman.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Jaundice.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }
    else     if (diarrhea.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && nausea.isChecked() && dehydration.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Cholera.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }
            else if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && shiver.isChecked()&& abdoman.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Malaria.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }
     else    if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && chills.isChecked()  && bonepain.isChecked() && jointpain.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Chickengunia.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }
       else   if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && chills.isChecked()&& diarrhea.isChecked()&& nausea.isChecked()&& sorethroat.isChecked()&& cough.isChecked()&& runningnose.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Swineflu.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }
      else   if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && chills.isChecked()&& rashes.isChecked()) {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Typhoid.class);
                startActivity(Intents);

            }
            else
            {
                Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Checkup.class);
                startActivity(Intents);
            }
            }

    });

}
```

}

> This is my class file and it executes only the first if statement because the buttons I selected are in that statement.

Comment: conditions for viral fever is subset of chickengunia means if chickengunial is true then viral must be true. Since viral class condition executes first, you are   redirected on viral page. Try to create difference in logic for both and based on that redirect on proper page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(isHeadeck&& isPain&&isSweat&&isChills){
        if(jointPin&&isBonepain)
            Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Chickengunia.class);
             startActivity(Intents);
        else
        Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, ViralFever.class);
        startActivity(Intents);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
The problem seems to be that your check for `ViralFever` is written before your `Chickengunia` statement. What happens is that it first checks for symptoms for `ViralFever` which has the same subset of symptoms as that of `Chickengunia`.

**Solution:**
What you can do is swap the code for `ViralFever` and `Chickengunia`.

```
if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && chills.isChecked()  && bonepain.isChecked() && jointpain.isChecked()) {
            Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, Chickengunia.class);
            startActivity(Intents);

        }

  else     if (headache.isChecked() && sweating.isChecked() && weakness.isChecked() && chills.isChecked()) {
            Intent Intents = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, ViralFever.class);
            startActivity(Intents);

        }
```

and so on...